# D3 - call function from enter()

Tags: d3.js

I have a stackblitz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/chart-update-1-34uvdo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbar-chart.ts

I have a D3 bar chart in an Angular app.

The bar are created with a start and finish position.

To show if it started higher or lower than the finish I have arrrows on top of the bars.

I'm using the general update pattern to redraw the graph when the data changes.

My problem is the arrows dont update when the data does.

I think I need to create the arrows in the enter part of the pattern.

How can I call the function from the enter part.

```
///Enter
    bar.enter()
      .append("rect")
      .classed('bar', true)

      .attr("x", (d, i) => {
        return this.x(d.phase)
      })

      .attr("width", (d, i) => {
        return this.x.bandwidth()
      })
      .attr("y", (d, i) => {
        if(d.start < d.finish){
          return this.y(d.finish);
        }else{
          return this.y(d.start);
        }
      })
      .attr("height", (d, i) => {
        if(d.start < d.finish){
          return this.y(d.start) - this.y(d.finish);
        }else{
          return this.y(d.finish) - this.y(d.start);
        }
      })
      .each( function(d, i) {
        //call arrow function here
      })
```

Comment: create `g` elements that contain the `rect` and the `line`

Comment: Two g elements ? One for the rect, one for the line?

Comment: one `g` per bar-line combo